# Transmission Line and capacitive effect

Tags: transmission-line, capacitance, impedance

I am driving a digital pin with a 10Mhz signal. At the pin, the signal's rise time is slewed to 35us such that the signal is no longer a pulse but a triangular waveform that does not reach the full output level of 1.8V. I have a source termination resistor on the driving source. However, this source is a couple of feet away and the trace is not a controlled 50Ohms. Would making this trace a controlled 50hms helped with the slewing of the rising time? Does line termination help or is this only to reduce reflections?
Also,if 50 ohms would help, is it better to have a discontinous 50 ohms or none at all? I have some transitions on the trace that I cannot make 50 ohms.

Comment: Is it the correct shape at the source?

Answer (score 3):

The source termination resistor value should be equal to the impedance of the transmission line minus the output impedance of the driving IC \$\left(R_\text{source}=R_\text{TL}-R_\text{out}\right)\$. It should be placed as close as possible to the driving IC.  Don't be surprised if you have to try a couple different values to get the signal to be perfect.

When using source termination you are actually cutting the signal that goes out in half. It looks full scale because when you match the source termination to the line impedance you get a perfect reflection, hence a doubling and the signal looks full size when scoped.

So, yes, matching the impedance of the line to the source termination impedance is critical for operation at 10MHz over several feet.

> I have some transitions on the trace that I cannot make 50 ohms.

What do you mean by transitions?  Cable couplers?  You're not splitting this signal off to more than one place I hope?  That will really not work, especially with source termination.

In the case that you're dealing with things that aren't perfectly 50 ohms (or whatever impedance cable you're using) you should first avoid them if at all possible.  Use couplers that are closely matched to 50ohm (they'll never be perfect) etc.

Any time the impedance changes in a transmission line there will be reflections -- the larger the change in impedance the larger the problem is and they can occur on both sides of the change (secondary reflections on the far side).  If the transitions in the signal patch are just the cable connectors on either end you can minimize their effect by placing the driving and receiving ICs as close as possible to them.  They usually do influence the overall TL impedance some, which is why you may have to tweak the source termination resistor a few ohms either way to get it perfect.

*In response to the OP's comment:*

There could be excess capacitance due to a faulty cable or connector.

However more likely, you can not, ever, tap off a high frequency signal with a source termination.  You will get nasty reflections.  If you need to tap off a signal like this it needs to be end terminated PAST the final tap, and each tap needs to be as close as possible to the transmission line.

I assume that this interface board is tapping into the signal somehow. If not don't use it and just figure out how to plug the output of the ATE directly into your device board.  If you provide some models for these parts I can probably be of more help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What is the source impedance of the driver?

What is the source/sink currents?

What is the impedance of the load?

What kind of cable?

What size is the termination resistor on the driver output and how is it
connected?

If the termination resistor on the driver output goes from the driver output
to ground you are reducing your output drive current. If this value is small
enough you will not be able to charge the cable capacitance and you will
reduce your rise=time.

If your driver is low-impedance you could add a series termination resistor
and then use 50Ohm cable. At 10MHz I think your problem is more basic -- not
enough current drive for the capacitive load.

Comment: +1 my guess would be capacitive loading, too.  That rise time is orders of magnitude slower than it should be, I don't see it being a termination problem.